# Issue with installing RPI Cam Web Interface

Tags: raspicam, software-installation, raspbian-buster

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 with a Raspberry Pi Camera V2. Fresh install of Buster on my microSD card. Only thing I've changed is the desktop background. My aim is to use RPi_Cam_Web_Interface for astrophotography.

I enabled the camera in preferences and ran install.sh.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/RPi_Cam_Web_Interface $ sh install.sh

+ readlink -f install.sh

+ dirname /home/pi/RPi_Cam_Web_Interface/install.sh

+ cd /home/pi/RPi_Cam_Web_Interface

+ dpkg-query -W -f=${Status} dialog

+ grep -c ok installed

+ [ 1 -eq 0 ]

+ color_red=tput setaf 1

+ color_green=tput setaf 2

+ color_reset=tput sgr0

+ versionfile=./www/config.php

+ cat ./www/config.php

+ grep 'APP_VERSION'

+ cut -d ' -f4

+ version=v6.6.9

+ backtitle=Copyright (c) 2015, Bob Tidey. RPi Cam v6.6.9

+ jpglink=no

+ phpversion=7.3

+ [ ! -e ./config.txt ]

+ source ./config.txt

install.sh: 72: install.sh: source: not found

+ rpicamdirold=

install.sh: 74: install.sh: Bad substitution
```

I'm not very technical and know very little programming. The lines from the install script cited from the traceback are:

```
source ./config.txt

rpicamdirold=$rpicamdir

if [ ! "${rpicamdirold:0:1}" == "" ]; then

rpicamdirold=/$rpicamdirold

fi
```

I don't know what I can do so this installs and functions.

Thank you.

P.S. This is the config file

```
#This is config file for main installer. Put any extra options in here.

rpicamdir="html"

webserver="apache"

webport="80"

user=""

webpasswd=""

autostart="yes"

jpglink="no"

phpversion="7.3"
```

Comment: The install instructions at https://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface are slightly different from your steps - it may be worth trying those?

Comment: I performed steps 1-4.
Step 5, I performed the git clone.
Since I'm using Buster, I didn't have to execute:

> cd bin
> mv raspimjpeg raspimjpeg-buster
> mv raspimjpeg-stretch raspimjpeg
> cd ..

And then I ran the install shell script. Same results.